# Wordpress register settings - images

Tags: wordpress, settings, image-uploading

I tried to add image uploader to my template settings page, I got this:

```
<?php

function pp_admin_init(){
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_name');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_title');
    //Odnosniki ikon
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_share_facebook');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_share_twitter');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_share_google');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_share_pinterest');
    //czy wyswietlac ikony
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_icon_facebook');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_icon_twitter');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_icon_google');
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_icon_pinterest');
    //Image test
    register_setting('pp_theme_options', 'pp_image_upload', 'pp_image_upload');
}
//image test    
function pp_image_upload($args){
if(!empty($_FILES['pp_image_upload']['tmp_name']))
{
  $overrides = array(
    'test_form' => false
  );
  $banner_image = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['pp_image_upload'], $overrides);
  $args['pp_image_upload'] = $banner_image['url'];      
}else{
  $args['pp_image_upload'] = get_option('pp_theme_options')['pp_image_upload'];
}
return $args;
}   
//image test    


add_action('admin_init', 'pp_admin_init');

function pp_settings_page() {
    ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/admin.css">    
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2>Ustawienia szablonu Photography+</h2>
            <div id="pp-settings">
            <form action="options.php" method="post" id="pp-options-form">
                <?php settings_fields('pp_theme_options'); ?>
                <!-- Image test -->                 
                    <input type="file" name="image_upload" />                       
                     <?php
                        echo '<img src="' . pp_image_upload . '" style="width: 100px; vertical-align: top;" />';
                    ?>          
                <!-- Image test -->
                <center><h1>Ustawienia ogólne</h1></center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_name">Twoje imię</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_name" id="pp_name" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_name')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_title">Twój tytuł</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_title" id="pp_title" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_title')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                    
                <center><h1>Adresy ikon społecznościowych</h1></center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_share_facebook">Facebook</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_share_facebook" id="pp_share_facebook" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_share_facebook')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_share_twitter">Twitter</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_share_twitter" id="pp_share_twitter" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_share_twitter')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_share_google">Google +</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_share_google" id="pp_share_google" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_share_google')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><label for="pp_share_pinterest">Pinterest</label></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_share_pinterest" id="pp_share_pinterest" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('pp_share_pinterest')); ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <center><h1>Widoczność ikonek</h1></center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Facebook</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_icon_facebook" id="pp_icon_facebook" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'pp_icon_facebook' ) ); ?> /><label for="pp_icon_facebook">Włącz/wyłącz widoczność ikonki Facebooka</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Twitter</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_icon_twitter" id="pp_icon_twitter" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'pp_icon_twitter' ) ); ?> /><label for="pp_icon_twitter">Włącz/wyłącz widoczność ikonki Twittera</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Google+</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_icon_google" id="pp_icon_google" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'pp_icon_google' ) ); ?> /><label for="pp_icon_google">Włącz/wyłącz widoczność ikonki Google+</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Pinterest</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="pp_icon_pinterest" id="pp_icon_pinterest" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'pp_icon_pinterest' ) ); ?> /><label for="pp_icon_pinterest">Włącz/wyłącz widoczność ikonki Pinterest</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                            
                <div class="pp_send"><input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="zapisz" /></div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <?php

}

function pp_settings_menu(){
    add_theme_page('Photography+  - Ustawienia', 'Szablon Photography+', 'manage_options', 'pp-theme-options', 'pp_settings_page');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'pp_settings_menu');

//powiadomienie dla admina
function show_admin_panel_message() {
    $key = esc_attr(get_option('pp_name'));
    $keyt = esc_attr(get_option('pp_title'));

    if(empty($key)) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p><strong>Szablon Photography+ wymaga dodania Imienia do strony głównej</strong></p></div>';
    }
    if(empty($keyt)) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p><strong>Szablon Photography+ wymaga dodania Tutułu do strony głównej</strong></p></div>';
    }
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'show_admin_panel_message');
```

?>

All forms are working but except image uploader. Can someone explain me how to add image uploader to custom settings page? As you can see in code I don't know how to use `add_settings_field`. I was taught this method, and now I just want to expand my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than fixing this code, is to do it the WordPress way.

You're registering some Settings in `pp_admin_init` but not using them in `pp_settings_page`. Use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) as it should be. Check all the External References in that Codex article, many heavy weights have written good tutorials. This other Codex page also has a good example: [Creating Options Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#Example_.232).

For the upload issue also: do it the WP way. You'll have to create a button that pop ups the default uploader, so the image handling/uploading is done live and your form/settings will simply store the image ID/URL. Here's [one article of interest](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) and [relevant posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=uploader%203.5) at WordPress Answers.